# Теряется часть JSON при получении его в DjangoRest

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

Отправляю следующий JSON:

```
{"delivery":{"delivery_time":"2016-05-31T12:18:47Z","delivery_adress":"123","phone":"123"},"paymentMethod":{"id":"1","title":"123124123"},"summ":"23","success":false}
```

Сериализатор:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    delivery = DeliverySerializer(required=False, allow_null=True)
    paymentMethod = PaymentsSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ( 'delivery', 'paymentMethod','summ','success') #'id',

    def create(self, validated_data):
        deliverys_data = validated_data.pop('delivery')
        delivery = Delivery.objects.create(**deliverys_data)
        paymentsMethod_data = validated_data.pop('paymentMethod')
        data=list(paymentsMethod_data.values())[:3]
        print(data)
        payment_method = Payments.objects.create(**paymentsMethod_data)
        order = Order.objects.create(delivery=delivery,paymentMethod=payment_method,**validated_data)
        return order
```

Пытаюсь получить id, чтобы его с помощью Object get использовать в ordere, а не создавать каждый раз новый, но каждый раз получаю только: [u'123124123'], данные только по названию . На данный момент заказ создается но каждый раз создавая новые методы оплаты

И я не понимаю куда он пропадает

View

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def order_post(request, format=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Другие сериализаторы

```
class DeliverySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Delivery
        fields = ('delivery_time','delivery_adress','phone')#'id', 
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Delivery.objects.create(**validated_data)   


class PaymentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Payments
        fields = ('id','title') #
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Payments.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы передаете информацию о методе оплаты, serializer поле id игнорирует - оно только для чтения. А так как в serializer не передается аргумент instance, то он создает новый метод оплаты с помощью метода create.

Если метод оплаты менять не надо, то `paymentMethod = PaymentsSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True)` надо убрать. Тогда поле будет принимать только id существующих методов оплаты. Запрос будет такой:

```
{
    "delivery":
        {
            "delivery_time":"2016-05-31T12:18:47Z",
            "delivery_adress":"123",
            "phone":"123"
        },
    "paymentMethod": "1",
    "summ":"23",
    "success":false
}
```

Но возвращать в ответе будет тоже id. Если нужно другое поведение, надо будет логику OrderSerializer или PaymentsSerializer.

Comment: Возвращает BadRequest

Comment: Что в теле ответа возвращает?

Comment: "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."

Comment: Посмотрите, не обернут ли у вас словарь {...} в список [...].

Comment: {"delivery":{"delivery_time":"2016-05-31T12:18:47Z","delivery_adress":"123","phone":"123"},"paymentMethod":"1","summ":"23","success":false}
Вот этот запрос отправляю, выглядит все в порядке

Answer (score 1):

Для таких случаев создается несколько сериализаторов, обычно три:

- сериализатор списков, содержащий только минимально необходимое количество полей
- сериализатор для детального просмотра записи
- сериализатор создания/обновления записи

Если следовать этой логике, то у Вас должен быть примерно такой код (в общем виде):

**app.serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from rest_framework.serializers import PrimaryKeyRelatedField
from .models import ModelClass
from anothermodel.models import AnotherModel # Связанная модель
from anothermodel.serializers import AnotherModelListSerializer

class ModelListSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    """
    Сериализатор для списка.

    Как правило, в списках нужно выводить только общие свойства модели, 
    а внешние ключи можно и вовсе спрятать
    """

    class Meta:
        model = ModelClass
        exclude = [ "related_model" ] # Внешний ключ, сейчас его не нужно сериализовать


class ModelDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    """
    Сериализатор для детальной информации о записи.

    Поле related_field будет сериализовано, и на клиенте мы увидим
    JSON-объект с вложенными полями.
    """

    related_model = AnotherModelListSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = ModelClass


class ModelWriteSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    """
    Сериализатор для создания/обновления модели.

    С клиента нужно передавать только id для модели, 
    с которой будет связано поле related_field. Параметр queryset
    указывает набор объектов, с которыми можно выполнить связь.
    """

    related_model = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=AnotherModel.objects.all(),
        write_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ModelClass
```

Теперь где-то в описании вида:

**api.movelviews**

```
from app.models import ModelClass
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from app.serialziers import ModelListSerializer, ModelDetailSerializer, ModelWriteSerializer


class ModelClassViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    queryset = ModelClass.objects.all() # а можно и get_queryset переопределить

    def get_serializer_class(self):

        if self.request.method == "GET":
            if self.action == "list":      
                return ModelListSerializer # GET: /api/models/
            return ModelDetailSerializer   # GET: /api/models/:id/
        return ModelWriteSerializer        # POST, PUT, etc к /api/models/ и /api/models/:id/

    class Meta:
        model = ModelClass
```

Comment: Спасибо, интересно, сейчас попробую на практике реализовать

Comment: Но немного другая задача у меня. Я отправляю серверу 1 JSON и хочу его записать в разные модели

Comment: Delivery.objects.create() работает как форсированное создание модели и сохранение её в базе. Подробнее тут: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.create

Comment: Другими словами, каждый раз вызов вашего сериализатора будет создавать новую запись. Вместо этого слеует использовать  функцию get_or_create - если записи не будет в БД, Django автоматически её создаст: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create